# Recovery: OS X Yosemite can not mount NTFS partition but windows can mount it in 10 minutes

Tags: macos, hard-drive, windows, mount, data-recovery

I have a Seagate GoFlex 2TB external HDD that stopped working one month ago. The head of this external disk seeks continuously and produces sounds even when it is not connected to the USB port.

On OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 it takes about 5 minutes to detect its hardware and show its icon in Disk Utility or in `diskutil list`. When my mac detects the hardware it shows Initialize/Ignore/Eject message and no more thing happens.

On Windows 7 it takes about 10 minuets (while the progress bar fills) to mount it. But it is very very slow on every operation. For example it takes 2 minutes to open a folder and so on.

If its partition is lost, why OS X cannot mount it? Is it a time out problem for OS X in mounting operation? How can i backup its contents with preserving folder structure faster?

Comment: Sounds entirely a drive fail issue. Mount it on whatever it will mount on & attempt recovery from there. My guess would be you will get incomplete recovery with anything other than a data recovery service, & all the time you're banging the heads around, you're lessening your chances. Throw it away & recover backup would be the simplest/cheapest solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't back it up on OS X, then back it up on Windows. Then format it something else other than NTFS, as OS X doesn't officially support it. If you re-format it using Windows, you can choose the default FAT/exFAT option.

Comment: As the rate of transfer is between 50-128 KB/s it takes about one year to back it up in Windows if there is no gaps. OS X supports NTFS partitions as read-only. The question is a recovery problem.